# Checking app installed for open ppt,pdf files

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uidocumentinteraction

How to check wheather any app is installed to open PPT,PDF in device.if any app installed in the device i want to show one alert,so kindly suggest me.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do first is find out if the PDF readers you want to interact with have URL Schemes on them. So you probably want to search for some PDF apps like `GoodReader` and `Adobe Reader`. Once you have found them you can simply use the `canOpenURL:` method to check if you can open your PDF using the URL Scheme. So your code might look something like.

```
- (void)openPDFFromURL:(NSString *)pdfUrlStr
{
    // Create our url out of the string passed in.
    NSURL *url = [NSURL urlWithString:[pdfUrlStr stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    // Check that we can actually open the url.
    // If the app for the url scheme you have passed in exists 
    // it will return true. Also see additional comments after code.
    if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:url]) {
        UIAlertView *successAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] 
                              initWithTitle:@"Success"
                              message:@"You can open the URL"
                              delegate:self
                              cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
                              otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil];
        [successAlert show];
        // You could also provide the below line to actually 
        // open the url
        // [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
    } else {
        // We are able to open the url
        UIAlertView *failedAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] 
                              initWithTitle:@"Failed"
                              message:@"You can't open the URL"
                              delegate:self
                              cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
                              otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil];
        [failedAlert show];
    }
}
```

If you don't know any apps that have URL Schemes for opening PDFs you could just pass in a URL for a PDF location on a website and it will actually do the check to see if it can open in safari.

Note that I'm not aware of what the URL Schemes are for any apps for opening PDFs you'll have to find these out yourself the code above only checks if the param you pass in can be opened and provides a `UIAlertView` based on the outcome.

Comment: BOOL isValid =  [documentInteractionController presentOpenInMenuFromRect:[button frame] inView:[[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window] rootViewController].view animated:YES]; i am using like this if any app is insatalled the boll value set but i dont this way.so kindly suggest another way to do this check

Comment: I have just suggested a different way from the way you have done it. Also you need to be providing what you have done already and saying you want a different way in your question. Please update your question to say exactly what you want and include all relevant code and not just two lines of zero information that tells us nothing.